# Broadcast receiver doesn't get called after closing the app

Tags: broadcastreceiver

I am using Android version 4.4.4 Hauwei device to run.

When I open my application its broadcast receiver is just working fine, but when I close the app by closing all recent applications, the broadcast receiver just stops to trigger. I have searched a lot, but I can't find the solution.

Permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

I have already put the receiver in the manifest file:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".MySmsReceiver"
        >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="COM.EXAMPLE.SIVA.MAINACTIVITY" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>
```

And this is my broadcast receiver:

```
   public class MySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "sms received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  }
```

After clearing recent applications I checked My application in Default settings application there my applications force stop button is being disabled..

Answer (score 1):

The Android docs on [manifest-declared receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) describe change in Android behavior that blocked implicit broadcasts. They also link to an alternative approach.

> If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use [scheduled jobs](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a service:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".SomeService"
        android:process="com.example.SomeService"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
```

SomeService.java

```
public class SomeService extends Service{

   public static final String START_SERVICE = "start";
   public static final String STOP_SERVICE = "stop";

   private SomeReceiver someReceiver;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case START_SERVICE:
                if (someReceiver == null) {
                    createReceiver();
                }
                registerReceiver(intent);
                startForeground((int) Thread.currentThread().getId(), new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext()).build());
                break;
            case STOP_SERVICE:
                unregisterReceiver();
                stopSelf();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createReceiver() {
        someReceiver = new SomeReceiver();
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    }

    private void registerReceiver(Intent intent){
        unregisterReceiver();

        registerReceiver(someReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void registerReceiver(){
        unregisterReceiver();

        registerReceiver(someReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver(){
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(someReceiver);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This receiver is listening to time ticking. (ACTION_TIME_TICK - is happening once a minute)

```
public class SomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.i("SomeReceiver", "Tick");   
    }

}
```

ActivityMain.java

```
...
startService(this, SomeService.class);
...
```

So for now it's not required to register receiver in AndroidManifest.xml.

Hope, it helps

Comment: I hav added that android:process="COM.EXAMPLE.SIVA.MySmsReceiver"

Comment: That was a bad answer.

Comment: You have to create service and run receiver from there.

Comment: I have already tried somethin like this that wasn't work for me.. and start foreground ll put a notification that ll always showing... I don't want that thing...